# Delete duplicate rows from a table on the basis of column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table say `PromoDescription`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| PromoId | Value | PromoType  |NightType|
--------------------------------------------------
|   101   |   11  |      a     |     b   |       
|   102   |   12  |      a     |     b   |       
|   103   |   17  |      c     |     d   |       
|   104   |   14  |      c     |     d   |
```

Above table has 4 columns and I have added the sample values.

**Problem:** For the same combination of `PromotionType` and  `NightType`, I have to keep the highest value of discount and delete the rest of rows.

For sample values, row 1 and 4 should be deleted.

Comment: you don't have to delete the rows, you can try group by promotype, nighttype and order by value, select the top 1 and you will have your result set. By keeping the rows you will have a history of changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check:

```
with c as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by PromotionType, NightType order by [Value] desc) as n
    from PromoDescription
)
delete from c
where n > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE to perform this:

```
;with cte as
(
  select promoid, value, promotype, NightType,
    row_number() over(partition by promotype, NightType order by value desc) rn
  from yourtable
)
delete
from cte
where rn > 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4968/4)

This will delete from the table anything that does not have the max value:

```
| PROMOID | VALUE | PROMOTYPE | NIGHTTYPE |
-------------------------------------------
|     102 |    12 |         a |         b |
|     103 |    17 |         c |         d |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join like this:

```
DELETE table1 
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(Value) as MaxValue, Promotype, nighttype FROM table1
   GROUP BY Promotype, nighttype
  )A
  ON table1.value = A.MaxValue
  AND table1.Promotype = A.Promotype
  AND table1.nighttype = A.nighttype
  WHERE A.MaxValue IS NULL;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42963/1)

Result

```
| PROMOID | VALUE | PROMOTYPE | NIGHTTYPE |
-------------------------------------------
|     102 |    12 |         a |         b |
|     103 |    17 |         c |         d |
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `NOT EXISTS` but this is just a variation on the general theme:

```
select *
from yourtable a
where not exists
  (
  select 1
  from yourtable b
  where 
      a.PromoType = b.PromoType and
      a.NightType = b.NightType and
      a.Value < b.Value

  )
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4968/6)